# firefox: keys is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm getting `.keys is not a function` on every object, using firefox 32beta but also with earlier firefox versions. Unsure what's is the cause?

```
var controls={'txt':{},'btn':{}};
alert(controls.keys());
```

Comment: It's `Object.keys(someobject)`, not `someobject.keys()`

Comment: @georg I think you put this here as a comment right as I was entering it as an answer :)

Comment: @TML: yeah, I'm somehow not in the answering mode today ))

Comment: `Object.keys(someobject)` - is Yoda master a TC39 member of?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you want [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), you should use `Object.keys(controls)`. See the MDN link for details.

Comment: I hate that it's this way around.